# How can I improve the performance of this huge nested loop? (Fortran 90)

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'll post the whole code segment here, but the only issue really is the nested loop at the end. All read-in matrices are of dimension 180x180 and the loop is unbearably slow. I don't see an easy way to simplify the calculation, since the index-wise multiplications to get the matrix "AnaInt" are no simple matrix products due to the threefold occurance of the indices. Any thoughts? Thanks!

```
program AC
 implicit none
  integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
  integer :: n, ndim, k, j, i, o, l, m, steps
  real(dp) :: emax, omega, pi, EFermi, auev
  complex(dp) :: Grs,Gas, ACCond, tinyc, cunit, czero, cone

  complex(dp), allocatable :: GammaL(:,:)     
  complex(dp), allocatable :: GammaL_EB(:,:)  
  complex(dp), allocatable :: GammaR(:,:)     
  complex(dp), allocatable :: R(:,:)  
  complex(dp), allocatable :: Yc(:,:)         
  complex(dp), allocatable :: Yd(:,:)         
  complex(dp), allocatable :: AnaInt(:,:)     
  complex(dp), allocatable :: H(:,:)         
  complex(dp), allocatable :: HamEff(:,:)     
  complex(dp), allocatable :: EigVec(:,:)    
  complex(dp), allocatable :: InvEigVec(:,:)  
  complex(dp), allocatable :: EigVal(:)       
  complex(dp), allocatable :: ctemp(:,:)      
  complex(dp), allocatable :: ctemp2(:,:)      
  complex(dp), allocatable :: S(:,:)          
  complex(dp), allocatable :: SelfL(:,:)     
  complex(dp), allocatable :: SelfR(:,:)     
  complex(dp), allocatable :: SHalf(:,:)      
  complex(dp), allocatable :: InvSHalf(:,:)   
  complex(dp), allocatable :: HEB(:,:)
  complex(dp), allocatable :: Integrand(:,:)


!Lapack arrays and variables
  integer :: info, lwork
  complex(dp), allocatable :: work(:)       
  real(dp), allocatable :: rwork(:)    
  integer,allocatable :: ipiv(:)

!########################################################################

!Constants
    auev = 27.211385
    pi = 3.14159265359
    cunit = (0,1)
    czero = (0,0)
    cone = (1,0)
    tinyc = (0.0, 0.000000000001)


!System and calculation parameters
    open(unit=123, file="ForAC.dat", action='read', form='formatted')
    read(123,*) ndim, EFermi
    lwork = ndim*ndim

    emax = 5.0/auev
    steps = 1000 


    allocate(HEB(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(H(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(Yc(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(Yd(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(S(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(SelfL(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(SelfR(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(HamEff(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(GammaR(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(GammaL(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(AnaInt(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(EigVec(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(EigVal(ndim))
    allocate(InvEigVec(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(R(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(GammaL_EB(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(Integrand(ndim,ndim))

!################################################



    read(123,*) H, S, SelfL, SelfR
    close(unit=123)

    HamEff(:,:)=(H(:,:) + SelfL(:,:) + SelfR(:,:))   



    allocate(SHalf(ndim, ndim))
    allocate(InvSHalf(ndim,ndim))
    SHalf(:,:) = (cmplx(real(S(:,:),dp),0.0_dp,dp))

    call zpotrf('l', ndim, SHalf, ndim, info)         
    InvSHalf(:,:) = SHalf(:,:)
    call ztrtri('l', 'n', ndim, InvSHalf, ndim, info) 

    call ztrmm('l', 'l', 'n', 'n', ndim, ndim, cone, InvSHalf, ndim, HamEff, ndim) 
    call ztrmm('r', 'l', 't', 'n', ndim, ndim, cone, InvSHalf, ndim, HamEff, ndim) 
    call ztrmm('l', 'l', 'n', 'n', ndim, ndim, cone, InvSHalf, ndim, GammaL, ndim) 
    call ztrmm('r', 'l', 't', 'n', ndim, ndim, cone, InvSHalf, ndim, GammaL, ndim) 
    call ztrmm('l', 'l', 'n', 'n', ndim, ndim, cone, InvSHalf, ndim, GammaR, ndim)
    call ztrmm('r', 'l', 't', 'n', ndim, ndim, cone, InvSHalf, ndim, GammaR, ndim)

    deallocate(SHalf)
    deallocate(InvSHalf)




!In the PDF: B = EigVec, B^(-1) = InvEigVec, Hk = EigVal

    allocate(ctemp(ndim,ndim))
    ctemp(:,:) = HamEff(:,:)
    allocate(work(lwork),rwork(2*ndim))
    call zgeev('N', 'V', ndim, ctemp, ndim, EigVal, InvEigVec, ndim, EigVec, ndim, work, lwork, rwork, info)
    if(info/=0)write(*,*) "Warning: zgeev info=", info
    deallocate(work,rwork)
    deallocate(ctemp) 

    InvEigVec(:,:)=EigVec(:,:)
    lwork = 3*ndim
    allocate(ipiv(ndim))
    allocate(work(lwork))
    call zgetrf(ndim,ndim,InvEigVec,ndim,ipiv,info)
    if(info/=0)write(*,*) "Warning: zgetrf info=", info   ! LU decomposition
    call zgetri(ndim,InvEigVec,ndim,ipiv,work,lwork,info)
    if(info/=0)write(*,*) "Warning: zgetri info=", info ! Inversion by LU decomposition (Building of InvEigVec)
    deallocate(work)
    deallocate(ipiv)


 R(:,:) = 0.0_dp
 do j=1,ndim
 do m=1,ndim
 do k=1,ndim
 do l=1,ndim
 R(j,m) = R(j,m) + InvEigVec(j,k) * GammaR(k,l) * conjg(InvEigVec(m,l))
 end do
 end do
 end do
 end do





!!!THIS IS THE LOOP IN QUESTION. MATRIX DIMENSION 180x180, STEPS=1000

 open(unit=125,file="ACCond.dat")

     !Looping over omega
     do o=1,steps
         omega=real(o,dp)*emax/real(steps,dp) 
         AnaInt(:,:) = 0.0_dp
         do i=1,ndim
             do n=1,ndim
                 do j=1,ndim
                      do m=1,ndim
                           Grs = log((EFermi-(EigVal(j)+tinyc)+omega)/(EFermi-(EigVal(j)+tinyc)))
                           Gas = log((EFermi-conjg(EigVal(m)+tinyc))/(EFermi-omega-conjg(EigVal(m)+tinyc)))
                           Integrand = (Grs-Gas)/(EigVal(j)-tinyc-omega-conjg(EigVal(m)-tinyc))

                           AnaInt(i,n)= AnaInt(i,n) + EigVec(i,j) * R(j,m) * Integrand(j,m) * conjg(EigVec(n,m))
                      end do
                 end do
             end do
        end do 

         Yc = 1/(2.0*pi*omega) * matmul(AnaInt,GammaL)
         Yd(:,:) = - 1/(2.0*pi) * cunit * AnaInt(:,:)

          ACCond = czero
          do k=1,ndim
              ACCond=ACCond+Yc(k,k) + 1/(2.0) * Yd(k,k)
          end do
          write(125,*) omega, real(ACCond,dp), aimag(ACCond)
      end do



!#############################################

    deallocate(Integrand)
    deallocate(HEB)
    deallocate(Yc)
    deallocate(Yd)
    deallocate(HamEff)
    deallocate(GammaR)
    deallocate(GammaL)
    deallocate(AnaInt)
    deallocate(EigVec)
    deallocate(EigVal)
    deallocate(InvEigVec)
    deallocate(H)
    deallocate(S)
    deallocate(SelfL)
    deallocate(SelfR)
    deallocate(R)
    deallocate(GammaL_EB)
end program AC
```

So, here's the first adaption according to the suggestions:

```
HermEigVec(:,:) = 0.0_dp
do i=1, ndim
do j=1, ndim
HermEigVec(i,j) = conjg(EigVec(j,i))
end do
end do

HermInvEigVec(:,:) = 0.0_dp
do i=1, ndim
do j=1, ndim
HermInvEigVec(i,j) = conjg(InvEigVec(j,i))
end do
end do


R(:,:) = 0.0_dp

R = matmul(InvEigVec,matmul(GammaR,HermInvEigVec))


open(unit=125,file="ACCond.dat")

    !Looping over omega
     do o=1,steps
         omega=real(o,dp)*emax/real(steps,dp)

         AnaInt(:,:) = 0.0_dp
             do j=1,ndim
             do m=1,ndim
                 Grs = log((EFermi-(EigVal(j)+tinyc)+omega)/(EFermi-(EigVal(j)+tinyc)))
                 Gas = log((EFermi-conjg(EigVal(m)+tinyc))/(EFermi-omega-conjg(EigVal(m)+tinyc)))
                 Integrand(j,m) = (Grs-Gas)/(EigVal(j)-tinyc-omega-conjg(EigVal(m)-tinyc))
                 T(j,m) = R(j,m) * Integrand(j,m)
             end do
             end do
         AnaInt = matmul(EigVec,matmul(T,HermEigVec))


         Yc = 1/(2.0*pi*omega) * matmul(AnaInt,GammaL)                      
         Yd(:,:) = - 1/(2.0*pi) * cunit * AnaInt(:,:)

         ACCond = czero
         do k=1,ndim
             ACCond=ACCond+Yc(k,k) + 1/(2.0) * Yd(k,k)
         end do
       write(125,*) omega, real(ACCond,dp), aimag(ACCond)
     end do
```

Comment: What compiler flags are you using?

Comment: I'm a beginner in compiled coding languages, so TBH I only use "check" in ifort since you recommended it in another thread.

Comment: The flag `check` can slow down code a lot because it is ensuring the bounds of arrays are satisfied (as well as several other things). Since you are clearly not reaching over bounds, drop `-check` and add `-O3` (capital o, not 0).

Comment: Didn't really help, I think the whole loop has to be restructured in some way, but I cannot see how. EDIT: O3 is interesting, and I see it's optimizing for loops. Strange that it's still this slow

Comment: I threw in a `call cpu_time(start)` before the `do j=1,ndim` and another after the `enddo` for the `j` loop; it says (for `ndim=180`) that it takes about 1.1 seconds for each `j` loop, leading to roughly 10 hours total run time.

Comment: That is to say, you're more than likely not going to get this code to run any faster without parallelizing it.

Comment: I see that you are doing `matmul` calls.  In my personal testing, I did not find any case where LAPACK routines were not faster than `matmul`.  Seeing as you are already using LAPACK, I suggest replacing `matmul` with the appropriate LAPACK routine to squeeze some more juice out of your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your code.
Let's start with the loop before the one that you emphasize (it's easier to understand, but the following big loop has more or less the same problem).

So we have a loop on i, j, k, l.

You could consider reordering your loops, for better cache access. Your most inner loop is on l, which only appears as column index. With [column-major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) arrays in Fortran, you can expect bad performance from that. An inner loop on j would probably be better.

Much worse, your whole loop is a matrix update by a product of three matrices (InvEigVec * GammaR * InvEigVec^H), but you do it in O(ndim^4). Each matrix product is O(n^3) (or maybe less if you call optimized [ZGEMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Matrix_Multiply), using [Strassen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm)). Hence, two products should be O(n^3), not O(n^4), by storing matrix products.
That is, you can do a matrix product, then a matrix product-update.

---

Now, your big loop: *steps* times over i, n, j, m.

If I read well, you write

```
Integrand = (Grs-Gas)/(EigVal(j)-tinyc-omega-conjg(EigVal(m)-tinyc))
```

Where all variables on right-hand side are scalars, but Integrand is a ndim*ndim matrix. Much work to copy one value in multiple places.
But then you loop on the Integrand, where you could use simply a scalar. Or maybe it's a bug and you should have Integrand(j, m) or alike in left-hand side?

Then, your four inner loops are like in the preceding comments, an update of 
AnaInt with array product EigVec * (R .* Integrand) * EigVec^H, with .* the (term by term) scalar product of arrays (or just EigVec * R * EigVec^H if Integrand is just a scalar).

Again, it would probably be good to try to write this with ZGEMMs, thus lowering the complexity a lot.

Comment: oh, these are alot of things to try, thanks. Give me a minute to check your suggestions

Comment: so, I think the main thing i missed is that Integrand is indeed a scalar if you define it WITHIN the j-m-loop. So once it is set as a certain number, i can do a matrix multiplication (matmul,lapack) EigVec <dot> R <dot> EigVec^H and then simply multiply it by the scalar value of Integrand?

Comment: Wow. Setting `Integrand(j,m)` changes from having a 1.1 second loop over all `j` values to taking 4e-3 seconds.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems to me you should make Integrand an array, storing its possible values depending on indices j, m (outside the 4 inner loops, or maybe even updating R by multiplying by the corresponding elements of Integrand). Then I think you can write the whole 4 loops more easily (and much faster) with matrix products.

Comment: Damn I didn't think that through. Obviously it's not pretty to have whole matrix multiplications in the inner loop. I am still unsure how to weite this in lapack/matmul-statments because one cannot simply sum over j and m. EDIT: ah arbautjc, good idea. I'll try that. EDIT2: btw, Integrand depends on omega, which is looped over in the "o"-loop

Comment: Yes, you can't "escape" the o loop, but the 4 inner loop are indeed one (quite) simple matrix formula. And it's never a good idea to write products of several matrices with imbricated loops with scalar products as basic operations - it's much faster to multiply two matrices at a time (and when dimensions are different, positions of (implied) parenthesis are very important)

Comment: I have added my adaption to the main post. it yields the correct result for a simple 2x2 test system, but the 180x180 only prints out zeros. I'm still looking for a bug.

Comment: it's running now. And it's running fast. A few seconds compared to months. thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a parallelization over the loops using OPENMP ? It's pretty easy to implement. If interested I could give you some hints maybe.

Try to take a look here: [openMP DO tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#DO)

Comment: Once the algorithm is transformed from O(n^4) to O(n^3), it may be a good idea to call parallelized ZGEMMs, to optimize further...